# Error Message:Could not start conversion. Could not get directory. Null directory for 'F:\'

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, gac

I am facing some weird issue from last few days.
I have one dll that converts `HTML` to `PDF`.
If i have kept my application in E drive then it is running & working as expected.

But the moment I have change the location of the my application then that dll is throwing below error
I don't know what is wrong with the dll.

Is there any possibility that this issue is related to `GAC`

```
Error Message:Could not start conversion. 
Could not get 'evointernal.dat' directory. 
Null directory for 'F:\'.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: nope my file location is D//folder//folder//folder

Comment: **EDIT** Could there be a hard coded reference to E:\ in your dll?

Comment: @Chris No there is no any hardcoded reference bcoz If i placed my application in E drive then it is working as expected, so what could be the issue

Comment: How do you pass the file location to your conversion method? Did you try to pass the fully qualified path? i.e `C:\Temp\yourfilename`?

Comment: @Chris how can i found that there is hardcoded reference

Comment: Could you please attach the code that you use to pass the file for conversion? Not much to go with without a code sample. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why the issue should be related to assemblies being in the GAC...

Very probably you are using relative paths, and when the application is running from the E drive it finds the paths and when running from F it does not.

Change your code to always verify the existence of directories and files before trying to access them, that would already be an improvement. And check your code for the use of relative paths.

Comment: I am able to acccess all the directoris & files except one DLL.